# how to convert part of the string to int/float/vector3 etc. without creating a temp string?

Tags: c#, string, garbage-collection, immutability

in C#, I have a string like this:
"1 3.14 (23, 23.2, 43,88) 8.27"
I need to convert this string to other types according to the value like int/float/vector3, now i have some code like this:

```
public static int ReadInt(this string s, ref string op)
{
    s = s.Trim();
    string ss = "";
    int idx = s.IndexOf(" ");
    if (idx > 0)
    {
        ss = s.Substring(0, idx);
        op = s.Substring(idx);
    }
    else
    {
        ss = s;
        op = "";
    }
    return Convert.ToInt32(ss);
}
```

this will read the first int value out, i have some similar functions to read float vector3 etc. but the problem is : in my application, i have to do this a lot because i received the string from some plugin and i need to do it every single frame, so i created a lot of strings which caused a lot GC will impact the performance, is their a way i can do similar stuff without creating temp strings?

Comment: You can safely change `string ss = "";` to just `string ss;`. Right now you're creating an empty string object in memory that is never used.

Comment: @musical_coder: you are correct that the code does not need the assignment. However, it doesn't create an empty string. Since he's using the string literal `""`, it just references the _existing_ interned empty string. At worst, it wastes time copying that reference to the variable, and in practice the JIT compiler will probably optimize it away. Still, I agree it should be omitted, simply for clarity. Otherwise, someone reading the code might think the default value is meaningful and valid.

Comment: thanks for the comment, i'm trying to figure out if there is function like Convert.ToInt32(ss, startIndex, count), so i don't need even one temp string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generation 0 objects such as those created here may well not impact performance too much, as they are relatively cheap to collect. I would change from using `Convert` to calling `int.Parse()` with the invariant culture before I started worrying about the GC overhead of the extra strings.

Also, you don't really need to create a new string to accomplish the `Trim()` behavior. After all, you're scanning and indexing the string anyway. Just do your initial scan for whitespace, and then for the space delimiter between `ss` and `op`, so you get just the substrings you need. Right now you're creating 50% more string instances than you really need.

All that said, no...there's not anything built into the basic .NET framework that would parse a substring without actually creating a new string instance. You would have to write your own parsing routines to accomplish that.

You should measure the actual real-world performance impact first, to make sure these substrings really are a significant issue.

I don't know what the "some plugin" is or how you have to handle the input from it, but I would not be surprised to hear that the overhead in acquiring the original input string(s) for this scenario swamps the overhead of the substrings for parsing.